# How to insert text into onlyoffice webword?

Tags: javascript, sdk, onlyoffice

I want to insert text into word, but I can not find the api;

```
let docEditor = new DocsAPI.DocEditor("placeholder", config);

docEditor.insertText('simple text') // this is I want to do, but insertText is undefine
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read this url
https://api.onlyoffice.com/docbuilder/textdocumentapi 
sample code:

```
builder.CreateFile("docx");
var oDocument = Api.GetDocument();
var oParagraph = oDocument.GetElement(0);
oParagraph.AddText("This is just a sample text. Nothing special.");
builder.SaveFile("docx", "AddText.docx");
builder.CloseFile();
```